# jQuery data in JavaScript works with id but not without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

jQuery json data is easily fetched from PHP without any issue. if i want to display same data with  it is coming without any issue but js file is external file not embedded in html. so if i want to pass the value of jQuery var into JavaScript it is not working but it is working in same HTML file with id.

here is my jQuery external file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        $('#upload-form2').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data) {
                var html = '';
                var sthtml = '';
                var ndhtml = '',
                    downlo;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    z = i + 1;
                    downlo = data[i];
                    html += '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + z + '</td></tr>';
                    sthtml += '' + downlo.stchart + '';
                    ndhtml += '' + downlo.ndchart + '';
                }
                $('#down-btn').html(html);
               $('#checkk').html(sthtml);
              $('#chek').html(ndhtml);
                $('#saving-details').html(html);
               }
        })
    })();
  });
```

if i am padding checkk and chek id to  data is correctly being displayed data is { x: 1, y: 59 },{ x: 2, y: 93 },{ x: 3, y: 477 },{ x: 4, y: 506 }
 but when i try to pass the same variable in datapoints of canvasjs nothing is coming. 
i tried setting those sthtml and ndhtml as global variable by declaring before ready function.did not worked.
tried ''+sthtml+'' in datapoints did not work. tried canvasjs tutorial but they are passing external json file but i want to pass jquery var data as all data are already fetched correctly in jquery.

is there anyway i can add data to below datapoints other than i tried below. like  but canvasjs will not accept this div in datapoints so some other way required

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var sthtml = [];
    var ndhtml = [];
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        axisY: {},

        data: [{
            dataPoints: [sthtml]
        }, {
            dataPoints: [ndhtml]
        }],

        legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            itemclick: function(e) {
                chart.render();
            }
        }
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
```

it is not duplicate as the referred question did not identify the root cause even so its different

Comment: @VishwasR its not working, i already tried that so the real problem was not identified in that thread so i started new one

Comment: @VishwasR but i think u r best to guide as u work for canvasjs

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle or static html with the issue along with the sample json data which you are using, so that we can understand the issue better and help you out.

Comment: I tried creating it locally to understand it better. As far as I understood, on submit of form(id 'upload-form2') you are trying to populate data through 'sthtml', on 'document.ready'. But you are rendering chart on 'window.onload', both has to be handled accordingly to make it work properly.  Also I observed that chart doesn't have any dataPoints as the y-value is undefined (Please check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/fmpdn3)

Comment: @VishwasR thanks for your reply. i was populating my data in top as well so that i am sure my json is correct. here is screenshot .top left in page http://prntscr.com/fmphmj . you can see that json is correct however it is adding object Object as i am defining those variables globally at top of page with sthtml={};  if i define by sthtml='' those object object goes but i think we must define so i am not removing. i think that object object is making json invalid to pass with canvasjs so i am trying to trim that object object and will update.

Comment: The prefix 'object Object' is not the string. [object Object]{ x: 3, y: 66.8 }, means that there is an array of objects ([object Object]) and an object ({x: 3, y: 66.8}) after that (refer this screenshot for more info: http://prntscr.com/fmps7m). Please check the format properly. dataPoints in CanvasJS is array of objects. If you form array of objects and pass it to dataPoints, it should work fine.

Comment: @VishwasR thx.then god knows what mistake i am doing. i tried with jquery replace that did not work but if i pass direct value in push it works dps.push({ x: 1, y: 450 },{ x: 2, y: 414});  works without issue .seems that jquery variable value is being pushed in html which is under div id but unable to pushed into script tag variable data and its blank however i have declared it globally